# angular input[date] ng-model format

Tags: angularjs, format

When use input[date] in angular, the input format is DD/MM/YYYY but the value of ng-model is in format YYYY-MM-DD.

Is it possible to change the format of the value to DD/MM/YYYY?

```
<input type="date" ng-model="date" class="DateInput"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angular-ui-mask` to change the format to [DD/MM/YYYY] `ui-mask='99/99/9999'`.

Answer (score 0):

add a $watch,when date changed,format date to DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Angular Date filter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

```
{{date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```